# Combine in PowerShell a path with spaces and a variable and parameters

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I have a PowerShell script that works when the path to the exe doesnt have spaces but doesnt work with spaces. How can i fix this?

```
$dir = "path/to/directory"
$images = Get-ChildItem $dir
foreach ($img in $images) {
  $outputName = $img.DirectoryName + "\" + $img.BaseName + ".webp"

  ##### The line below works well when there are no spaces
  ##### C:\webp-converter\libwebp-0.6.1-windows-x64\bin\cwebp.exe $img.FullName -o $outputName

  ##### How do i change the syntax to make the line below work?
  C:\Program Files\a folder with many spaces in the title\bin\cwebp.exe $img.FullName -o $outputName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&` call operator:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\a folder with many spaces in the title\bin\cwebp.exe' $img.FullName '-o' $outputName
```

or with the executable path in a variable:

```
$dir = "path/to/directory"
$images = Get-ChildItem $dir
$exe = "C:\Program Files\a folder with many spaces in the title\bin\cwebp.exe"
foreach ($img in $images) {
  $outputName = Join-Path $img.DirectoryName ($img.BaseName + ".webp")

  & $exe $img.FullName '-o' $outputName
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works, thanks. And if i want to make the path a variable? for example, at the same line to add `$pathtoexe $img.FullName '-o' $outputName` and than define the path. How do i define it? do i have to define it in the foreach?

Comment: @EPurpl3 saving the path to a variable would work the exact same, yes :) updated the answer